# How to access published attributes of pubnub from view in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, handlebars.js, pubnub

In my rails project I use pubnub to live update few things and I use handlebars for live update template. Below is the code to publish the update

```
subscriber_channels.each do |subscriber_channel|
            $pubnub_server_subscription.publish(
                :channel => subscriber_channel,
                :message => {event: 'LIVE_FEED',
                             attributes: {
                                 live_feed_id: self.id,
                                 feedable_type: self.feedable_type,
                                 feedable_id: self.feedable_id,
                                 profile_picture_url: "#{self.action_user.profile_photo_thumb}",
                                 action_user_name: "#{self.action_user.full_name}",
                                 live_feed_content: "#{self.content}",
                                 feed_time: "#{self.created_at.strftime("%H:%M")}",
                                 reference_post_id: reference_post_id,
                                 reference_post_type: self.reference_post_type
                             }
                },
                callback: lambda { |info| puts info }
            )
          end
```

and for template my code is below

```
PUBNUB_CLIENT.events.bind("LIVE_FEED", function (message) {
var livefeedTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#top-live-feed-template').html());
              var outputHtml = livefeedTemplate(message.attributes);
              $('#live-feed-table').prepend(outputHtml);
}
```

So far above code works just fine. But I need to do some checking before I call the template. I want something like this

```
    PUBNUB_CLIENT.events.bind("LIVE_FEED", function (message) {
if feedable_type == "image" #this feedable_type from published attributes above
        var livefeedTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#top-live-feed-template').html());
                      var outputHtml = livefeedTemplate(message.attributes);
                      $('#live-feed-table').prepend(outputHtml);
        }
    }
```

feedable_type here is the published attributes from above. So how can I do this? Or how can I do something like this?

```
console.log( "update a <div> with received event: feedable_type");
```

Comment: Are you using the PubNub Gem or the the PubNub JavaScript SDK ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PUBNUB_CLIENT.events.bind("LIVE_FEED", function (message) {
    if(message.attributes.feedable_type == "image"){
        var livefeedTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#top-live-feed-template').html());
        var outputHtml = livefeedTemplate(message.attributes);
        $('#live-feed-table').prepend(outputHtml);
    }
}
```

If that would not work, please, provide a bit more details.